# WP7, WP8 How to set several ResourceDictionaries to use custom FontFamilies

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I want to set custom fonts for some controls, so if I set a font inside the only **one** ResourceDictionary and use it in styles then everything **works just fine**. But this approach is not fine for me, because I need to have font declarations in a **separate** dictionary then styles that are using them.

In `App.xaml` I have made several Resource Dictionaries

```
<Application ...> 
   <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ResourceAgencyDictionary.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ResourceCommonDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources> 
   ....
</Application>
```

In `ResourceAgencyDictionary.xaml` I have `MyFontFamilyNormal` declaration

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <FontFamily x:Key="MyFontFamilyNormal">/GBAgencyCommon;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Gotham Book</FontFamily>
    .....    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In `ResourceCommonDictionary.xaml` I want to use that font family (`MyFontFamilyNormal`):

```
 <ResourceDictionary ...>
        <Style x:Key="MyTextBlockValueStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MyFontFamilyNormal}"/>
            ....
        </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

The project compiles but I get a runtime error

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233087
  _message=**Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key MyFontFamilyNormal**

Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Comment: This is called knowledge exhibition... You got your answer right? Close the topic then.

Comment: I solved it after I've ask it and placed here. At that time there is no checkbox which was while creating "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style". And if I close the question now what radio button should I select? duplicate / off topic / not constructive / not a real question / too localized ?? Nothing fits

Comment: if you can ad answer your own question now then you can close this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, searched the solution a lot in Internet and just found it.
The solution was simple (I've tried it but with wrong path to file and didn't notice that it was the right direction)

so in `App.xaml`

```
<Application ...> 
   <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ResourceCommonDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources> 
   ....
</Application>
```

the `ResourceAgencyDictionary.xaml`  is the same

in `ResourceCommonDictionary.xaml`

```
 <ResourceDictionary ...>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceAgencyDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style x:Key="MyTextBlockValueStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MyFontFamilyNormal}"/>
            ....
        </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

NOTE: `Source="ResourceAgencyDictionary.xaml"` because this file is in the same folder as `ResourceCommonDictionary.xaml`