# Is there any way to reuse the same custom font in resource dictionaries?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I do the following:

```
<!--Ресурсы приложения-->
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <FontFamily x:Key="DefaultFontFamily">/KingsSquare;component/Fonts/HeinrichScriptRegular.ttf#HeinrichScript</FontFamily>                  
                <kingsSquare:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper" />
                <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KingsSquare" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
            </ResourceDictionary>


            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Buttons.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Text.xaml" />                

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>    
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I can't use `DefaultFontFamily` in `Buttons.xaml`. The following line in a style inside `Buttons.xaml` throws an exception which says that the key is not found.

```
 <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFontFamily}"></Setter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you didn't add MergeDictionaries in Buttons.xaml.
Look this answer:[WP7, WP8 How to set several ResourceDictionaries to use custom FontFamilies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828872/wp7-wp8-how-to-set-several-resourcedictionaries-to-use-custom-fontfamilies)